# Are there two or four movements for each rep of a Single-Leg Romanian deadlift?

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, you-are-your-own-gym

The description in the book describes touching the right hand in front of the left foot while the right leg goes up, then says to repeat it with the left hand going down, and that you've completed one rep when you've done that. Then, it says to switch legs. So, when doing ladders (1 rep, then 2 reps, then 3 reps, etc), is one to do the right leg twice as one rep, then do left twice, right twice as the second two reps, and so on? Or is "one rep" supposed to be twice on the right and twice on the left?

I would consult his website, but [the forum](https://www.marklauren.com/forum/) seems to perpetually be down.

Comment: I guess the question is about the exercise at 0:06? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBdOaCakUEk

Comment: @Gyrfalcon: Yes, although the basic exercise doesn't have a hop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would understand touching one leg twice as one rep.

So your actual ladder would look like this: 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4 ... - because you are switching the legs

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think you can use a literal interpretation of that exercise description and superimpose “ladders” on top of it.  As described, you won’t risk losing any benefit from the exercise if you modify it to fit your needs.  In my opinion, you would be better off rotating each leg after each set.  So, for instance, the sequence might be…

> Set 1
>
> Right leg, 1 rep    Left leg, 1 rep
>
> Set 2
>
> Right leg 2 reps    Left leg 2 reps
>
> Set 3
>
> Right leg 3 reps    Left leg 3 reps

And so on…

At a minimum, the above scheme would certainly make it easier to keep track of where you are.